# Java LinkedList problems

Tags: java

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 2
    at java.util.LinkedList.checkElementIndex(LinkedList.java:553)
    at java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:474)
    at InterfacePackage.Main.main(Main.java:116)
Java Result: 1
```

Code (shortened) :

```
if(input.length() > 0)
{
    if(command.size() == 1)
    {
        switch(command.get(0).toLowerCase())
        {
            case "exit":
            case  "qqq":
                active = false;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("invalid input, for complete list of commands enter 'help'...");
                break;
        }
    }
    else if(command.size() > 1)
    {
        if(command.get(0).equalsIgnoreCase("shutdown") && command.size()==3)
        {
            Shutdown shutdown = new Shutdown();
            shutdown.Start(command);
        }
        else if(((command.get(0).equalsIgnoreCase("scan") 
            && command.get(1).equalsIgnoreCase("ips"))
            || command.get(3).equalsIgnoreCase("/e"))
            && (command.size()>=2 || command.size()<4))
        {
            SystemsIPs sips = new SystemsIPs();
            sips.Start(command);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("invalid input, for complete list of commands enter 'help'...");
        }
    }
}
```

The error occurs when the users enters two string within a line that doesn't exist in the `else if(command.size() > 1)` loop.

For example, if the user would enter : `hello world` the program produces this error.

So this is a program that does various things based on user input to a console. I've been getting this error and and wanting to know what is causing it. I know I can just catch it, but I really want to know what causing this error.

Comment: If you had to guess (or actually think up an informed answer), why do you think it happens?

Comment: You're requesting index 3 to a list of size 2.

Comment: Lol never mind, I see what I did wrong. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is how I solved the problem :

```
else if((command.get(0).equalsIgnoreCase("scan") && command.get(1).equalsIgnoreCase("ips")) && (command.size()>=2 || command.size()<4))
```

So I removed the

```
|| command.get(3).equalsIgnoreCase("/e"))
```

... from the code entirely, and improved the case in the separate class that this if statement directs to.

Here is what I did in the separate class...

```
if(command.size()==3 && command.get(2).equalsIgnoreCase("/e")) { }
else if(command.size()==2) { }
```

And it works (:

Answer (score 0):

Your error seems to be caused by

```
command.get(3).equalsIgnoreCase("/e"))
```

There is no index 3.  Check if that index exists first, before you do that.

Comment: ...or handle the exception when it fails.

Comment: that too, but conditionals are normally more efficient than exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` as it says, and it occurs when you're trying to access a position in a collection/array and that position is empty, you're trying to access to an index that doesnt exist. If you don't want that to happen then force the program to use an Collection with a size more than 3 element.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
else if(((command.get(0).equalsIgnoreCase("scan") && 
command.get(1).equalsIgnoreCase("ips")) || 
command.get(3).equalsIgnoreCase("/e")) && 
(command.size()>=2 || command.size()<4))
```

You are using `command.get(3)` to retrieve the 3rd element of the `LinkedList`, but it's not guaranteed that there are at least 3 elements in the list.

So you'd better add a condition `command.size() >= 3` before `command.get(3)`.